# Ubuntu server with GUI starting at console

Tags: command-line, server, gui, raspberrypi

I installed an ubuntu server 20.10 on a raspberry PI 4. Fine so far.
Then I installed Xorg.  (sudo apt install xorg)
After I reboot, the system starts at GUI (I belive GNOME, but I may be wrong).
I want the system to start at the console and not at the GUI. I will them start the GUI when I want to.
Is there a way to achieve this goal? Can you please help me achieving it?

Thanks

Comment: I installed ubuntu server 20.10 on a raspberry PI 4. There is no grub!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the Raspian OS then the option to do exactly what you want is in the raspi-config, it allows the disabling of the desktop loading then you can start when wanted. If not wanting to run that OS try this below, it is for Ubuntu a version older but probably still used by them.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-gui-on-boot-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
(sudo systemctl set-default multi-user) did the trick.

Comment: You are welcome, nice to see it worked for you.